# DIscord bot deletes 50 messages instead of 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

That's my code

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
     data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
         .setName('clear')
         .setDescription('Deletes shit')
         .addNumberOption(option => option.setName('amount')
             .setDescription('amount to clear')
             .setRequired(true)),
     permissions: [Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES],
     async execute(interaction) {
        const amount = interaction.options.getNumber('amount');
        interaction.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true);
        await interaction.reply(`Удалено ${amount} сообщение(сообщений)`);
     },
}
```

When I try to delete something my bot writes that he deleted null messages and deletes 50 messages. And if I enter 2, he deletes 100 messages. Please, help!

Comment: Not sure but try changing getNumber to getInteger :^

Comment: Unfortunately, Didn't help.

Comment: Log amount and see what it will log to the console

Comment: What did it give @BaTniK123 ?

Comment: @K.KDesgins it return null.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. I needed to just restart deploy-commands.js file. System just didn't notice my IntegerOption. I restarted deploy-commands.js and all is working now.